# How Javascript is getting executed in browser by Javascript Engine?

Tags: javascript, javascript-engine

**Question not for solution, Question to understand the system better**

Experts! I know whenever you feed javascript code into javascript engine, It will execute by javascript engine immediately. Since, I haven't seen Engine's source code, I have few of questions as follows,

Let us assume I am loading couple of files from remote server namely FILE_1.js and FILE_2.js.
And the code in FILE_2.js is requiring some of the code in FILE_1.js. So I have included files as follows,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="FILE_1.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="FILE_2.js" ></script>
```

So hopefully, I have done what Javascript Engine requires. Here unfortunately I have written 5000KB of code in FILE_1.js, and however I have 5KB of code in FILE_2.js. Since server is multi-threaded definitely FILE_2.js will be loaded into my browser before FILE_1.js completed.

How javascript engine handle this?

And If moved the code from FILE_2.js to inline-script tag as follows, what are actions taken by javascript engine to manage this dependency?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="FILE_1.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" >
// Dependent code goes here
</script>
```

Note: I am not expecting single word answer Single Threaded. I just want to know deep who is manage issuing request either browser or javascript engine or common guy? if the request/response is handled by common guy, then how javascript engine aware about this?

Comment: The server will wait for file 1 to fully load before executing file 2 because file 2 might depend on it. If they're independent you can always use a module loader, or add the `defer` attribute to the script.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum is correct, as long as you load them in that order. That said, I hope the 5000KB is a made-up number; that is *huge* for a client-side script!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When I post an answer about the behavior of code, I always like to go to two places:

1. The specification
2. The implementation

### The specification:

The DOM API explicitly specifies scripts must be executed in order:

> **If the element has a src attribute, does not have an async attribute, and does not have the "force-async" flag set**
> The element must be added to the end of the **list of scripts that will execute in order as soon as possible** associated with the Document of the script element at the time the prepare a script algorithm started.

From [4.1 Scripting](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/scripting-1.html#the-script-element). Please check the list of exceptions to this rule before - having the `defer` or `async` attribute. This is specified well in [4.12.1.15](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/scripting-1.html#the-script-element).

This makes sense, imagine:

```
 //FILE_1.js
     var trololo = "Unicorn";
     ....
     // 1 million lines later
     trololo = "unicorn";
     var message = "Hello World";
//FILE_2.js
     alert(message); // if file 1 doesn't execute first, this throws a reference error.
```

It is generally better to use a module loader (that will defer script insertion and execution, and will manage dependencies correctly for you).

At the moment, the best approach is to use something like [Browserify](http://browserify.org/) or [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) . In the future, we'll be able to use ECMAScript 6 modules.

### The implementation:

Well, you mentioned it and I couldn't resist. So, if we check the [Chromium blink](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/blink/trunk/Source/core/dom/ScriptLoader.cpp?revision=168105#l168) source (still similar in WebKit):

```
bool ScriptLoader::prepareScript(const TextPosition& scriptStartPosition, 
                                    LegacyTypeSupport supportLegacyTypes)
    {
    .....
    } else if (client->hasSourceAttribute() && // has src attribute
              !client->asyncAttributeValue() &&// and no `async` or `defer`
              !m_forceAsync                    // and it was not otherwise forced                                   
              ) { // - woah, this is just like the spec
   m_willExecuteInOrder = true; // tell it to execute in order
   contextDocument->scriptRunner()->queueScriptForExecution(this, 
                                                            m_resource,
                                      ScriptRunner::IN_ORDER_EXECUTION);
```

Great, so we can see in the source code that it adds them in order parsed - just like the specification says.

Let's see how a [script runner does](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/blink/trunk/Source/core/dom/ScriptRunner.cpp?revision=163261):

```
void ScriptRunner::queueScriptForExecution(ScriptLoader* scriptLoader,
                                          ResourcePtr<ScriptResource> resource,
                                          ExecutionType executionType){
     .....
     // Adds it in the order of execution, as we can see, this just 
     // adds it to a queue
     case IN_ORDER_EXECUTION:
        m_scriptsToExecuteInOrder.append(PendingScript(element, resource.get()));
        break;
     }
```

And, using a timer, it fires them one by one when ready (or immediately, if nothing is pending):

```
 void ScriptRunner::timerFired(Timer<ScriptRunner>* timer)
 {
 ...
    scripts.swap(m_scriptsToExecuteSoon);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    ....
        //fire!
        toScriptLoaderIfPossible(element.get())->execute(resource);
        m_document->decrementLoadEventDelayCount();
    }
```

Comment: since ECMAScript 6 is out, could you please update this answer? TIA

Comment: Why would that matter? It's a different spec from the DOM API

Comment: Since you pointed it is better to use module loader, and you said ES6 can be used to achieve it, i want to know more about this

Comment: @Mark ECMAScript 6 modules are not production ready at the moment (sadly) - they work but people still use webpack most of the time (and rightfully so)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum why es6 modules are not production ready ? All major browsers support it, except for IE. If you don't care about IE I would say it is safe to use es6 modules.